# Error reading binary file in Visual Studio using C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, file-io, char, binaryfiles

This may be less of a programming issue, but I need some help nonetheless. I'm learning how to work with file streaming and I was reading binary data from a file. I was saving the data into a char array to access the file's data byte by byte. At one point in the file, I store an unsigned int and in order to get it, I use a reinterpret cast to save the data to a variable. However, I kept getting random data and nothing I did fixed it. I even did some pointer arithmetic to get to the exact location of my unsigned int in the file. After messing around, I got tired and returned my code to its original state. I ran it again and, for some reason, I was reading my data correctly. Basically, code that I knew wasn't working before started working again. What would cause this sort of thing to happen? I know this is a long explanation but I've had this happen before and I would like to know what causes this. Feel free to ask me any clarifying questions, if any.

Here's an extremely simplified example of what I'm doing to get a better idea:

```
string binaryFile = "pathToBinaryFile.bin";
ifstream in(binaryFile, ios::binary | ios::in);

in.seekg(0, ios::end);
size_t totalNumOfBytes = inFile.tellg();
in.seekg(0, ios::beg);

char* savedData = new char[totalNumOfBytes];
in.read(savedData, totalNumOfBytes);

Node* node = reinterpret_cast<Node*>(savedData);

//Below is the line of code that kept breaking
unsigned int byteOffsetToNodeLocation = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(node.position);

node.position = reinterpret_cast<float*>(savedData + byteOffsetToNodeLocation);
```

Assuming I have a Node class that stores a pointer to a float (node.position), I first read the data of the Node object I stored into the file. In that data, I store an unsigned int that tells me how far into the file I need to look in order to find the float the Node's float pointer should point to. The issue is at the line with "byteOffsetToNodeLocation", where I continuously get random values, but suddenly worked again when I reverted all of the changes I made to fix it. I had others helping me that saw this happen first-hand. This is a very difficult issue to explain if you didn't see it yourself or haven't experienced something like this, so if you need more clarification, let me know.

Comment: Its really hard to say without seeing the code in question.  It may have been something as simple as you accidentally running a version that was not compiled with your latest code changes.

Comment: why do not you share your pseudo/partial c++ code which you have written so far for this?.

Comment: @LMAR1093 How about this explanation -- `your program has bugs`. Given that you've indicated that your using pointers, casting, etc. your program could be observing undefined behavior. When you make a mistake such as corruption of memory, buffer overruns, etc, then the running of that C++ program is *not* deterministic, i.e. it will predictably crash. Heck, it may run "ok" for years until that fateful day. Show us the code, and then we can see if your description matches exactly with what you have written.

Comment: I added some example code of what i'm doing. Also, regarding jeremy's comment, I made sure that the code I was running was recompiled with the latest changes. This is why I'm thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 0):

> code that I knew wasn't working before started working again.
>   Nothing can explain that, usually it's because you ran the code without re-compiling, or changed the file, or another simple explanation. It's frustrating but the compiler always produces the same result when given the same input ;)

The code looks good (storing an int in a float* is a bit unusual but should work). Did you touch the Node class ? Compiler sometimes adds padding to align data on 32 bits boundaries, that could be an issue. Is Node a class or a struct ? I mean if it has any virtual method that will blow up when you call one, though it looks like you don't have any virtual method.

Other think you could check is if byteOffsetToNodeLocation is smaller than totalNumOfBytes. If it is not, you are pointing outside of the savedData buffer and then the behavior of a read from  *node.position might be randomly crashing.

Another possible issue could be a previous instance having a lock on the file, preventing your code from reading it. (I don't know what is the sharing policy of ifstream). You should check that totalNumOfBytes is at least as large as sizeof(Node).

Comment: I made sure to recompile my code whenever I make changes before I even run it, so that wasn't the problem. I also only have one file to read from and I double-checked that my path went to that very file. It probably is a simple issue, but I'm probably to new to all this to figure that out. Better to ask than to be confused about what's going on.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a reply, it was to big to fit as a comment :(